# Rspecでconfirmダイアログのテストが通らない

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara

現在spec/system配下でテストを下記のように作成しているのですが、通りません。
Rspecのconfirmについての最新記事が下記の記事ぐらいしかなく、
解決方法が分かりません。ご教授頂ければ幸いです。

こちらの記事を参考に実装しております。
[【Rails】Selenium/RSpecでconfirmダイアログのテストをする - Qiita](https://qiita.com/at-946/items/403d85d45cb02615c323)

下記エラーが表示されます。

```
Capybara::NotSupportedByDriverError: Capybara::Driver::Base#dismiss_modal
Capybara::NotSupportedByDriverError: Capybara::Driver::Base#accept_modal
```

**データ削除の時に書いているコード**

```
<%= link_to "写真削除", post, method: :delete, id: 'delete_button', data: { confirm: "削除しますか?" } %>
```

**spec/system/aaa_spec.rb**

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe "AAA", type: :system, js: true do
  let(:user) { FactoryBot.create(:user) }
  let(:other_user) { FactoryBot.create(:user) }
  let(:img_path) { Rails.root.join("spec/img/aaa.jpg") }

  context "when a user posts a img" do
    it "test1" do
      visit new_user_session_path
      fill_in "メールアドレス", with: user.email
      fill_in "パスワード", with: user.password
      find('.signin-btn').click_link_or_button "ログイン"
      expect(page).to have_current_path root_path

      expect {
        upload_img(img_path)
      }.to change { user.posts.count }.by(1)

      expect(page).to have_current_path user_path(user)
      expect(page).to have_text "写真数(1)"
      expect(page).to have_selector '#post-1'
      expect(page).to have_selector '#favorite-form-1'

      click_button "お気に入り登録"
      expect(user.favorites.count).to eq 1

      visit users_path
      expect(page).to have_selector '#post-1'
      expect(page).not_to have_selector '#favorite-form-1'

      visit user_path(user)
      expect(page).to have_selector '#favorite-form-1'
      click_button "お気に入り取り消し"
      expect(user.favorites.count).to eq 0

      visit root_path
      find('#post-1').find('img').click
      expect(page).to have_selector '#showImgModal-1'
      expect(page).to have_selector '.post-delete', text: '写真削除'

      expect(page).to have_selector '#comment-form-1'
      within('#comment-form-1') do
        fill_in "コメント欄", with: "こんにちは"
        click_link_or_button "コメントする"
      end
      expect(user.comments.count).to eq 1
      expect(page).to have_selector '.comment', text: "コメント削除"

      page.dismiss_confirm("削除しますか?") do
        click_on :delete_button
      end
      page.accept_confirm do
        click_on :delete_button
      end
    end
  end
end
```

問題のコードの部分を下記に変更したらテストが全て通るようになった。
こちら本当に合っているのでしょうか？

```
page.dismiss_confirm("削除しますか?") do
  click_on :delete_button
end
page.accept_confirm do
  click_on :delete_button
end
↓↓
click_link "写真削除"
expect(page).to have_content "写真が削除されました"
```

**support/capybara.rb**

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:each, type: :system) do
    driven_by :rack_test
  end
end
Capybara.javascript_driver = :selenium_chrome_headless
```

Comment: コードを変更してテストが直ったのは、`rack_test`がJavaScriptをサポートしていないため、モーダルが表示されず、そのまま連続してボタンを押せるためかもしれません。

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara#racktest
公式ドキュメントによると、`Rack::Test`はJavaScriptをサポートしていません。よって、モーダルなどは動作しないことになります。

`support/capybara.rb`の内容を

```rb
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:each, type: :system) do
    driven_by :selenium_chrome_headless
  end
end
Capybara.default_driver = :rack_test
Capybara.javascript_driver = :selenium_chrome_headless
```

のようにしてみてはどうでしょう。この設定では、普段は高速な`rack_test`ドライバを使いつつ、JavaScriptの実行が必要な可能性のあるSystem Specsに対しては`selenium_chrome_headless`ドライバを使うことでJavaScriptのテストも可能にしています。

---

余談ながら、該当するエラーは
https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/blob/2ffbb3c6a55b9b3de13819b171c331ef9d125d4e/lib/capybara/driver/base.rb#L120-L145
で起きているようです。

Comment: ご教授頂きました、capybara.rbの設定を試したところ、system配下のテストが全て通らなくなりました。
system配下の全テストのエラー内容に、こちらが表示されます。
`Failure/Error: raise ActionController::RoutingError, "No route matches [#{env['REQUEST_METHOD']}] #{env['PATH_INFO'].inspect}"`

Comment: なるほど、もし可能であればspec/system/aaa_spec.rb`の全体を質問に記述していただければ原因がわかるかもしれません。

Comment: 上記エラーに関しては、`_parh`となっている箇所を`_url`に変更すると直る可能性があります。

Comment: ご指摘頂きましたcapybara.rbで`_path`となっているか箇所を`_url`に変更しても、エラー内容は変わらずでした。
又、私のcapybara.rbの設定で_pathと_urlの両方のケースを実行したら、
エラー内容がこちらに変化します。
`Capybara::NotSupportedByDriverError: Capybara::Driver::Base#dismiss_modal`

Comment: `ActionController::RoutingError`については、`_url`に変更しても直らないのであれば原因は私にはわかりません…

Comment: ここまでアドバイスして頂き有難う御座います！！
もう少し自分で探してみます！！